# asp.net MVC 4 - Many to Many data not updating - Updating Entity Framework with ViewModel Edit View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

asp.net mvc 4, Entity Framework 5, SQL Server 2012 Express

I have a Place model:

```
public virtual int PlaceID { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
public virtual string Name { get; set; }
```

and a related Tag model:

```
public virtual int TagID { get; set; }
public virtual string Name { get; set; }
public virtual string NamePlural { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Place> Places { get; set; }
```

many to many relationship.

There is a view with the following ViewModel associated. In it I can edit place details - and edit what tags are associated with the place (for example, the place might have a 'restaurant' tag and a 'bar' tag - and perhaps I want to add a 'cafe' tag, and remove 'restaurant' tag).

PlacesWithTagsViewModel:

```
public Place place { get; set; }
public ICollection<Tag> SelectedTags { get; set; }
```

When the view does an httpost back to controller - I update tags like this:

```
place.Tags = SelectedTags
db.Entry(ptvm.place).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

However, place properties update (eg Name) - but Tags always stay the same.

How can I update tags?

Comment: I had same problem. Finally, I've forced to first remove all child entities and then add new ones to the parent entity. If you want this approach, tell me to send you an example

Answer (score 0):

Avoid **db.Entry(ptvm.place).State = EntityState.Modified;** as it causes conflicts with no updation.

You must use **UpdateModel(table object, "model");**

Full Example is as belows :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PlaceTag(PlacesWithTagsViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       tag tagtest = GetTagById(model.tagid);
       tag.name= model.tag.name;
       tag.nameplural = model.tag.nameplural;
       UpdateModel(tag, "model");
       db.SaveChanges();
       return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard", new { id = 5 });
    } 
}
```

The advantage of UpdateModel is that you have to mention only those fields which you update avoiding those which remain static. In this way you can update your related data with Viewmodel in Edit View.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't explain well. No tag is updated here - I just need to update the tags associated with the Place. (many to many relationship). For example - a place can be tagged 'restaurant' and 'cafe'. I may want to associate an additional tag 'bar', and remove one 'restaurant', during the update.

Comment: can you also clarify what problem db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified; causes? Was it a bad idea for Microsoft to include this in scaffolding?

Comment: @user2254951 You will be facing concurrency conflicts(locking) by using  `db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;` 
A situation where you have two or more CRUD operations in the same controller action. So I prefer UpdateModel which stays optimistic in performance.

Comment: ok - any idea on my main question though - why related tags are not being updated?